# mongoose how to send transaction multiple collections

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, transactions

**Side-Note** I connect to DB with the following code:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const connectDB = (url) => {
  return mongoose.connect(url);
}
```

**Problem Description:**
I have two different Collections. Both Operations, `findByIdAndUpdate` and `create` must run as an atomic operation. This should be possible with mongoose Transactions.

```js
const registerCustomer = async (req, res) => {
   await CustomerRegistrationCode.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body._id, { used: true });
   const customer = await Customer.create({firstName: req.body.firstName});
}
```

**What I tried:**

```js
const registerCustomer = async (req, res) => {
    const session = await mongoose.startSession();
    await session.startTransaction();
    try {
        await CustomerRegistrationCode.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body._id, { used: true }); //updates even though 
        const customer = await Customer.create({ firstName: req.body.firstName });// this line will throw error
        await session.commitTransaction();
        session.endSession();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('abort transaction');
        await session.abortTransaction();
        session.endSession();
        throw error;
    }
}
```

**Problem** The CustomerRegistrationCode Collection gets updated even though the Customer.create method throws an error. How can this be solved?

**New approach to understand MongoDB Transactions** fails, but this is official code from https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const debugMongo = async () => {
  const db = await mongoose.createConnection("mongodb://localhost:27017/mongotest");
  const Customer = db.model('Customer', new mongoose.Schema({ name: String }));
  const session = await db.startSession();
  session.startTransaction();
  await Customer.create([{ name: 'Test' }], { session: session }); //(node:20416) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoServerError: Transaction numbers are only allowed on a replica set member or mongos
  let doc = await Customer.findOne({ name: 'Test' });
  assert.ok(!doc);
  doc = await Customer.findOne({ name: 'Test' }).session(session);
  assert.ok(doc);
  await session.commitTransaction();
  doc = await Customer.findOne({ name: 'Test' });
  assert.ok(doc);
  session.endSession();
}

debugMongo();
```

At `Customer.create` an error gets thrown and i don't know why. Does somebody have an minimal working example?

Answer (score 10):

You are using the transaction in a wrong way, that is why it does not work.

You need to pass the `session` object to your operations.

```
const registerCustomer = async (req, res) => {
    const session = await mongoose.startSession();
    session.startTransaction();
    try {
        await CustomerRegistrationCode.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body._id, { used: true }, { session });
        const customer = await Customer.create({ firstName: req.body.firstName }, { session });
        await session.commitTransaction();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('abort transaction');
        await session.abortTransaction();
    } finally {
        session.endSession();
    }
}
```

Also, I have refactored your code a bit.

You can read more about transactions [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html)

Comment: I guess the OP would want to use `withTransaction` instead of `startTransaction`, also because it basically encapsulates the `try/catch/finally` block that you have written, adding retryable writes.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Unfortunatley is @Ayzrian version not working for me. I get the error `MongoServerError: Transaction numbers are only allowed on a replica set member or mongos` in line `await CustomerRegistrationCode.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body._id, { used: true }, { session });`

Comment: Before using transactions read the documentation in MongoDB here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/ looks like you have a bad configuration.

Comment: Hi, I have added a code example to my post but this does not work and I don't know why because its from the official docs.,